# How to quickly type a C expression where the assigned-to variable is repeated?

Tags: vimrc

I sometimes want to type an expression like this:

```
table[row][col] = std::max(table[row][col], other_table[row+1][col+1])
```

(this is C++ code. Unfortunately there's no way in C++ to eliminate the duplication except by writing a helper function like `void update_max(auto& a, auto const& b) { a = std::max(a, b); }` but that possibility won't be considered here)

How can I type the repeated part (`table[row][col]`) quickly?

For simplicity, you may assume the expression is "simple" (you can match it with some simple regex such as `.*;(.\{-})=`), but solution for the general case is okay too. (the problem is that C++ grammar is very complex)

Comment: C and C++ both allow macros, so something like this would also work in both:  `#define replacePairMax(t,r,c,o1,o2) (t)[r][c] = std::max((t)[r][c], (t)[(r)+(o1)][(c)+(o2)])`, where the flurry of parens is to ensure complex argument expressions do not interact unexpectedly with order of operations.  Usage here: `replacePairMax(table, row, col, 1, 1)`.

Comment: @EricTowers Suggesting macros should probably come with a disclaimer about how any good modern optimizing compiler will usually produce the same code if you just turn the macro into a function. I'd advise only using function-like macros in C if you need to insert type names or pieces of C code into very repetitive and hard-to-get-and-keep-right code, or to implement a "language feature" like [libdill](http://libdill.org) or [coroutine.h](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) do - unless compiler and performance limitations force it.

Comment: @EricTowers The point of trying to do this in Vim is to avoid making the code unidiomatic C/C++ by using unfamiliar construction. (In this case `update_max` is not that bad, actually)

Comment: @user202729 : Macros are not unidiomatic C.

Comment: @EricTowers, macros are unidiomatic C++ (hint: `std::`), of course we could have used other tricks (references, template functions, lambdas...). I understand OP's point: sometimes we have `lhs = expression(lhs)`, and `lhs` is not that simple. Instead of augmenting _tracing_ by introducing a new function/macro that may not be used anywhere else, we just duplicate the `lhs` part. Vim can be good at doing this, so, let's see how!

Comment: @LucHermitte : You're apparently reading a different Question title than is actually there.

Comment: @EricTowers, I see a question about "typing", not about programming. :)

Answer (score 12):

You can repeat the last inserted text in insert mode using [`CTRL-R .`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) or [`CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-A)

But you need to leave insert mode to complete the change.  Enter insert mode and type

```
table[row][col]
```

Then leave insert mode and re-enter using <kbd>Esc</kbd>[<kbd>a</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#a) and type the rest of the line before the repeated part

```
table[row][col] = std::max(
```

Finally, type [`CTRL-R .`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) (or [`CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-A))

```
table[row][col] = std::max(table[row][col]
```

and finish the line.

Comment: `<C-A>` instead of `<C-R>.` saves one keystroke.

Comment: `CTRL-@` also inserts previously inserted text and additionally leaves the insert mode.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use a mapping:

```
inoremap <silent> sf <c-r><c-r>=getline('.')[:col('.')-2]->substitute('.*;','','')->substitute('=.*','','')->trim()<cr>
```

Or an abbreviation (if the keychain consists of only "normal" keys, it's preferred to mapping, as a mapping may conflict with a part of another word, such as `transform`):

```
abbr <expr> sf getline('.')[:col('.')-2]->substitute('.*;','','')->substitute('=.*','','')->trim()
```

(it's necessary to have `-2` because `col()` returns the 1-indexing index of the next character on the cursor, while `[:]` takes the 0-indexing byte index of the last character to be included)

This uses [function or "method" chaining](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#method), a feature [new to Vim 8.2](https://vimhelp.org/version8.txt.html#new-vimscript-8.2). For older version where such method calls are not available it's possible to instead use:

```
abbr <expr> sf trim(substitute(substitute(getline('.')[:col('.')-2],'.*;','',''),'=.*','',''))
```

So you only need to type

```
table[row][col] = std::max(sf, other_table[row+1][col+1])
```

The `sf` typed will expand to `table[row][col]` in this case.

Comment: You might want to point out that `->` (function chaining) is only available in Vim 8.2 (which most people probably haven't yet installed).

Comment: I took the liberty of adding links to relevant help docs.

Comment: Nice idea. Is there a reason for not using the simple `getline('.')[:col('.')-1]`

Comment: My mistake, it should be `col('.')-2` which also work with multibytes characters and tab before or under the cursor when used in `getline('.')`. `strcharpart()` has its use-cases, but it tends to complicate code and make it less portable with older flavours of vim.

Comment: EDIT: 
Beside on <tab>abcdéfgh, we can observe with inoremap µ <c-o>:echo getline('.')[:col('.')-2] . " -- " . strcharpart(getline('.'), 0, getpos('.')[2]-1)<cr> that strcharpart() solution does **not** return the correct substring.

Comment: To be more precise, the problem is that `col()` and `getpos()` return positions expressed in bytes while `strcharpart()` expect a number of characters. Then, we could think about using `virtcol()` (I did), alas it returns columns numbers that aren't easily compatible with the presence of tabulations. I'm afraid, the only simple combinations that work are the direct access + `col('.')-2` (in insert mode) to get up to the cursor (excluded), or `matchstr` + `/\%#` to have the character under the cursor, because of multi-bytes.

Comment: @LucHermitte Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For the given example, I would first type

```
table[row][col]
```

and then

```
<Esc>yBA
```

before continuing the statement, then leaving insert mode and pressing `p` to paste the expression when needed.

```
<Esc> " Leave insert mode
yB    " Yank the preceding WORD (moving the cursor)
A     " Move cursor to end of line and enter insert mode
```

---

I do think [Mass's similar answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22259/23564) is better, if you can recall it. I wasn't aware of it before reading.

Comment: It is nice that your answer keeps things simple. I also often use `YPJ`, which duplicates the line and leaves the cursor on a space added in the middle. `YPJx` is the same, without adding the space in the middle. `YPgJ` is the same as `YPJx`, but keeps the original line in the `"` register. `Dpp` duplicates the suffix of the current line starting at the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

As a "vi veteran" (30+ years) I may appear "old fashioned" but I prefer solutions working everywhere and always (without preparing much in a `.vimrc` file), even if they require a tiny amount of planning ahead:

First insert the line as:
`@ = std::max(@, other_table[row+1][col+1])` (+ `<Esc>` of course)

Then type:
`:s/@/table[row][col]/g` (+ `<Enter>` of course)

For the latter, if you need it again some time later, `q:` may be your friend … though this requires vim … but it is one vim's features I consider to be priceless.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resist [golfing](http://vimgolf.com/) this one, and came up with the following:

```
3itable[row][col]<Esc>i+1<Esc>F].;a, other_<Esc>3;a = std::max(<Esc>A)<Esc>
```

This works by inserting *three* copies of `table[row][col]` by using a [`[count]`](http://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#count) with the [`i`](http://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i) command and then jumping backwards to fill in the missing parts of the statement — each of which is conveniently adjacent to a `]` character — with the [`F`](http://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#F) and [`;`](http://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#;) commands.

It improves on [Mass's (actually far more appropriate) solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22259/343) by 5 "keystrokes" (55 vs 60), but would only actually be quicker to use in anger if you are *exceedingly* good at eyeballing `f` motion targets.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution:

```
inoremap <expr><C-G> get(split(getline('.'), '[[:blank:],;()]\+'), nr2char(getchar()) - 1, '')
```

Now pressing `<C-G>1` while editing the line will insert the first "word" of it. "The word" is anything bounded by blanks, commas, parentheses and semicolons. Feel free to edit the regex as you wish.

Comment: Why not use the `\<\w\+\>`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I suppose you mean `\W\+`, as this is a regex for separators, not for the words. That could work for text file, but for C program such regex would split `table[row][col]` into "table", "row", and "col" which is not the OP asks for. To cover the general case this should depend, at least, on `&filetype` and `&iskeyword` (`\k`).

Comment: Well, i really meant capture the right text rather than split on non-words, but sure. Yeah iskeyword is better

Comment: @D.BenKnoble But `[]` is not keyword in C.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and defining snippets for these operations.